# FLANN Python Bindings Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, flann

I've installed FLANN with the following command:

```
brew install flann --enable-python
```

But I cannot import the module from within Python:

```
In [4]: import pyflann
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b6d4c333a325> in <module>()
----> 1 import pyflann

ImportError: No module named pyflann
```

Both `flann` and `pyflann` don't work.  It would also be nice if I could make this module available within a virtualenv as well.

Help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!  I looked in here `/usr/local/Cellar/flann/1.8.4/share/flann/python` and saw a `setup.py` file.  I enabled my virtualenv and then ran `python setup.py install`.  It now works!